How to create a new iTerm2 with a keystroke and bring just this window to front
I've searched for quite a while now, I talked to numerous artificial intelligences, real intelligences and I tried many things including apple script and iTerms python API. But it seems impossible to me to achieve this.
TLDR
I want to use a keyboard shortcut to open a new iTerm (or Terminal) window which has focus without bringing all the existing iTerm (or Terminal) windows to front.
I don't care if this solution is for Terminal or iTerm2, to be honest, although I seem to like iTerm2.
The long story
Use case
Imagine I have 5 iTerm windows and safari open on a single screen. Now I quickly need another iTerm window to do something, but I don't want the other iTerm windows to clutter safari, because I want to have a glance at the web page at the same time I write into the terminal.
System info
I am on a Mac M3 pro
macOS Sonoma 14.5
iTerm2 Build 3.5.1
Current status
Currently I am using a python script which uses iTerm's python API to create a new window. This works. Unfortunately this window does not come to the front and does not have focus. Its always second to the currently focused window / app.
I use Hammerspoon to run the script.
The script is cluttered, because i tried different solution.
The script
#!/usr/bin/python3
import iterm2

import subprocess
import asyncio

def focus_window_applescript(window_id):
    script = f"""
    tell application "iTerm2"
        set id_list to every window's id
        set wnd_id to first item of id_list
        # echo windows
        set newWindow to (first window whose id is wnd_id)
        select newWindow
        # activate
    end tell
    """
    subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", script])

def focus_window_applescript_2(window_id):
    script = f"""
    tell application "iTerm2"
        -- Ensure we have windows available
        set id_list to every window's id
        set wnd_id to first item of id_list
        set wnd to first window whose id is wnd_id
        set wnd2 to first window
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTerm2"
            -- Ensure we have windows available
            #     set frontmost to true
            set index of wnd to 1
            perform action "AXRaise" of first window
        end tell
    end tell
    """
    subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", script])

def focus_window_applescript_3(wnd_id):
    script = f"""
    tell application "iTerm2"
        # set id_list to every window's id
        # set wnd_id to first item of id_list
        # set wnd to first window whose id is wnd_id
        set wnd to first window
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "iTerm2"
            # set oWin2 to first window whose name is winTitle
            set focused of wnd to true
            tell wnd to perform action "AXRaise"
        end tell
    end tell
    """

async def main(connection):
    app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    wnd = await app.windows[-1].async_create(connection)
    await wnd.async_activate()

    print(wnd)

    focus_window_applescript_3(wnd.window_id)

def is_iterm_running():
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "iTerm2"])
        return bool(output.strip())
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False

def check_focus_and_create_window():
    script = """
    tell application "System Events"
        set frontmostApplication to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    end tell

    if frontmostApplication is "iTerm2" then
        tell application "iTerm2"
            create window with default profile
        end tell
        return "true"
    else
        return "false"
    end if
    """
    result = subprocess.run(["osascript", "-e", script], capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result.stdout.strip() == "true"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if check_focus_and_create_window():
        exit(True)
    if not is_iterm_running():
        subprocess.Popen(["/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2"])
        # Wait for iTerm2 to start up
        # for i in range(5):
        #     print("sleep 1")
        #     sleep(1)  # Adjust sleep duration if necessary
    iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
    exit(True)

# async def main(connection):
#   app = await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
#   print(app.windows)
#   await app.windows[0].async_create(connection)

# iterm2.run_until_complete(main)


I am new to mac and was using Arch Linux with Gnome before. There it was super easy to achieve this :(
I am aware, that there might be a different work style to get around my demands, but adapting the work style woould be the last resort.
Any advice is appreciated
Thanks in advance

iTerm Preferences > Keys > Hotkey has settings "Create a Dedicated Hotkey Window". Could this help to achieve desired outcome?

@AivarPaalberg No, this is not the behavior I want. The Dedicated Hotkey Window does exactly what it says. It dedicates a (single) window to a hotkey. I want to open a new window every time I use this keyboard shortcut. Thanks anyways

Note that, in Terminal.app if you create a new window with a right-click on the dock icon you will achieve what you want. So you can write an AppleScript which uses accessibility frameworks to access the dock icon right-click menu. See Applescript click dock item and trigger a menu item for details. Then save it as a service and assign a global hotkey to it.
There of course exists more advanced methods, like getting the wid(windowid) of the new window and using SkyLight private methods to only bring it (& the application) to the front. But that's too hacky  and no open-source implementation exists as far as I know. Yabai has an (not very well explained) implementation of it, in window_manager_make_key_window. If you are good at programming this is the most universal way to go.

Thanks, I will try this out

This is far, far better than my initial brute force thought to anutomate app activation, iterate across all windows to send them to the back of the Ui stack and then summon the window. Good insight here @hym3242

@hym3242 This solution works. It took me some time to figure out how to exactly do this, but the link you provided was really helpful. I will post the script I ended up in a post below.

Based on the answer given by @hym3242 I came up with the following script:
tell application "System Events"
   tell application process "Dock"
      tell list 1
         tell UI element "iTerm"
            perform action "AXShowMenu"
            tell menu 1
               if menu item "New Window (Default Profile)" exists then
                  tell menu item "New Window (Default Profile)"
                     perform action "AXPress"
                  end tell
               else
                  tell menu item "Open"
                     perform action "AXPress"
                  end tell
               end if
            end tell
         end tell
      end tell
   end tell
end tell

I am running this script using hammerspoon. This is my code in init.lua:
local function runScript()
   hs.alerths.osascript.applescriptFromFile("/path/to/apple.scpt")
end

-- Bind the function to the key combination
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "ctrl"}, "T", runScript)

